# How can I make Windows 8 use the classic theme?

Tags: windows-8, themes

The answers I've seen are themes, which only give me the colours and not the appearance/performance of the UI; in addition, I want to keep Metro.

Basically this:

[image: Windows Classic, with bevels and shit]

Instead of:

[image: Fake as shit Classic; it's Aero pretending to be Classic]

Comment: currently, there is no theme. Ask a designer on http://www.deviantart.com/ to create one for you.

Comment: But it's been built into Windows for years now, I don't expect it to disappear.

Comment: "But it's been built into Windows for years now, I don't expect it to disappear." - Ah, how many times have I said this about some feature or another, only to have it promptly disappear from the next Windows version.

Comment: Actually, the classic theme is still there, even in Window Technical Preview 10.

There's a guy on thinkpads forum has got your question figure out with his very own method. 

... he figured out that the classic theme can be restored for new processes by closing the handle to a shared memory section named "\Sessions\<Session ID>\Windows\ThemeSection" in the WinLogon process. He had written a quick and dirty program to automate the task at startup.

For more detailed and download link go to forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=113024so go there and try on your own.

Comment: Anybody know how to make this work on Windows 10? Please see: http://superuser.com/questions/951981/windows-10-classic-theme

Answer (score 16):

Actually the Classic theme does not get you more performance on the modern hardware:

- Classic theme uses CPU to render all its elements;
- New theme (it's Aero-based but without transparency) uses the power of GPU to render UI.
  Graphics Processing Units have enough memory to keep many window images in memory, so that the windows does not have to be repainted when you switch to a window which wasn't visible. Thus you save processing resources to other tasks or merely preserve battery energy.

Having the above in mind, with Windows 8, Microsoft decided you can't turn off Desktop Window Manager (DWM) any more. However, if you stop **Themes** service, Windows will have to fallback to CPU-based window rendering similar to Classic theme.

However, the approach from How-To Geek in [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/685555/80304) seems better alternative to stopping a service.

Comment: "Classic theme uses CPU to render all its elements" - this depends on whether DWM is running and not on the theming.

Comment: "New theme (it's Aero-based but without transparency) uses the power of GPU to render UI." - if DWM is running, Classic theme also uses GPU.

Comment: @Anixx Classic theme doesn't use GPU. Well, of course, both use GPU to display graphics. The difference is Aero-based themes use hardware acceleration and video memory to cache rendered windows. It isn't the case with the classic theme which uses only GDI interfaces, and window needs repainting whenever it becomes visible. Surely, application itself can use hardware acceleration.

Comment: you are wrong, see my answer. Classic theme works well with DWM enabled and GPU 3D acceleration working.

Comment: @Anixx What I said is _Classic theme does not use DWM or GPU 3D acceleration_.

Comment: u are wrong, Classic theme can be enabled when DWM and GPU 3D acceleration are working. They do not depend on theme.

Comment: @Anixx When Classic theme is used on Windows 7, DWM is still running. But what does it prove? When rendering classic theme, Window manager does not use any GPU accelerated APIs. Of course, an application can use GPU 2D or 3D acceleration to render its content. These facts don't contradict each other, do they?

Comment: Windows 7 works differently from Win8. When Classic theme is used on Win7, DWM disables itself even still residing in memory. On Win8 one can make use of Classic theme while DWM (and GPU acceleration) is still functioning, see my answer. One also can use Classic theme having DWM disabled, similarly to Win7. There are different tweaking tools for these two options available.

Comment: If a system has an older, less capable, integrated GPU (e.g. old like it DX10 won't run on it) then I've found that perceived performance may be improved in this manner.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following program:

http://bertrand.deo.free.fr/TEMP/w8classic.zip
Forum link: http://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=113024

It allows you to have Classic look (disables the themes) but keeps DWM running:

[image]

Using this method all Metro apps and Start Screen remain functional.

If you want DWM disabled as well, try this program:

[Windows 8 no DWM](http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=383450)

After using it, rename the Resources folder.

But do not forget to enable Auto-login to desktop because both login screen and StartScreen need DWM.

[image]

This method makes Metro apps not working because they need DWM.

A third method is somwhat similar to the first one, but is reported not to work with the taskbar (or the taskbar needs to be restarted).
It uses a batch file and the [handle utility by sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx). As the first method, it keeps DWM running. You have to run them unde admin command prompt.

Use this

```
@echo off
FOR /F "delims=^T" %%G IN ('Handle Theme') do set output=%%G
FOR /F "tokens=6" %%G IN ('echo %output%') DO set handleid=%%G
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%G IN ('echo %output%') DO set pid=%%G
echo %handleid%
echo %pid%
Handle -c %handleid% -p %pid% -y
```

or this script

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
FOR /F "tokens=3,6 delims=: " %%A IN ('Handle Theme') DO (
ECHO handleid=%%B
ECHO Pid=%%A
Handle -c %%B -p %%A -y
)
```

or, alternatively a one-liner:

```
@FOR /F "tokens=3,6 delims=: " %%A IN ('Handle Theme') DO Handle -c %%B -p %%A -y
```

and you'll get something like this:
[image]

Source:
http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/173367-simple-hack-enables-classic-theme-in-windows-10-and-8-too/

With all three methods the task manager stops working so you have to install the [classic task manager from Windows 7](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-restore-the-good-old-task-manager-in-windows-8/).

---

**For advanced users** I recommend [this method though](http://winclassic.boards.net/thread/43/windows-classic-theme-resident-programs).

Additionally, one can apply [this tweak](http://winclassic.boards.net/thread/120/classic-theme-variations-adjusting-upmcalc) to make the menus looking more classic.

Comment: Any idea how this'd work in Windows 10? Please see http://superuser.com/questions/951981/windows-10-classic-theme.

Comment: there is also this "[Classic Experience Pack](http://www.windowsonwindows.com/tutorial-how-to-enable-windows-classic-theme-in-windows-8-x-t252.html)" (buggy?)

Comment: @eadmaster it is the same as the first program in this answer, uploaded by somebody else without link to the original.

Comment: @Mark Boulder all three methods should work on Win10 now. The first method initially did not work before the program was fixed for Win10.

Comment: the 3rd did not work for me, do you confirm the 1st is safe and working on Win10 final?

Comment: @eadmaster ask the author here: http://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=113024 or read the thread. AFAIK it now somewhat works in Win10 but worse than under Win8 (the taskbar is not perfect). The "enable classic theme now" function worked always under Win10 but installation prevuously did not. The third method should work, what did not work for you? It is the safest method. Possibly you did not put the handle utility and the bath file in the same directory. Try specifying the full path to the handle utility.

Answer (score 1):

I have classic theme working.
Quite simple.. Just setup auto logon, rename dwm.exe so winlogon.exe can't find it, and do the same for the resources folder ..\Windows\Resources\

Also good to import the classic theme colours registry settings from windows 7..

Use penetwork for metro network ui, use turn system icons on or off to get rid of Windows network icon.
Use Windows pe task manager (old style non dwm dependant, can be pulled out of Windows setup using shift f10, notepad,  open file, all files. Need en-us\taskbar.exe.mui).
Use clearlock instead of locking pc, replace sethc.exe for lock on 5x shift key.
Use classic shell for start menu, disable all metro and start screen references.
Google how to disable the explorer ribbon ui, do it.
Google how to disable Command bar, edit the shellstyle.dll in system32.
Use batterybar and disable low battery notifications if using a laptop, also disable icon using turn system icons on or off.
Disable lock and switch users.
Disable password on wake.
Set force auto logon key to automatically log on if you accidentally log off.
Google how to disable all hot corners, charms bar & mouse edge ui

Only problem with this..
Can't see any startup/shutdown messages
Can't use multiple user accounts
Insecure due to clearlock
Can't use metro apps
Can't use startscreen
Can't use ctrl alt del security screen
Can't use open with dialogue
Can't use network UI dialogue
Can't use autoplay dialogue
Can't use charms bar

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1q_nlcCjyA

Comment: For open with dialog there is an excellent program "Open with enhanced", in Win7 style but better.

Answer (score 0):

[This theme](http://kizo2703.deviantart.com/art/Windows-classic-theme-for-Windows-8-RTM-325642288) is described by HowToGeek as the closest one can get :

[How to Get Classic-Style Themes Back on Windows 8](http://www.howtogeek.com/133405/how-to-get-classic-style-themes-back-on-windows-8/)

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have stated, the old, non composited classic theme is gone, and all the other answers do is suggest you tweak the theme. Lets face it - its not a classic theme without a proper start button and menu. On the other hand, if you want all that modern/metro/windowsui/whatevertheycallitthisweek goodness, you need a start screen. You can probably use my solution, in conjunction with either classic, or new shiny windows 8 themes to get something that close enough to a windows XP or 7 system UIwise. It also contains a explorer tweaking tool that brings it closer to a classic windows explorer window

It takes a bit of tweaking to get it *just right* but you can get something pretty close to what you want with a combination of [classic shell](http://www.classicshell.net/) and small taskbar buttons set to "never combine" through the regular taskbar settings. You can also tweak to select the explorer style you want
[image]. In this case, I've created a new account (the horrible yellow wallpaper is a default!) and set this up like an XP system. You can also use a 7 style start button, and/or 7 style explorer settings.

You can use the start screen menu as you see here to access the start screen/metro.I do believe you can also pin that in order to get a modern ui/strat screen launcher, and presumably set another shortcut to it.

[image]

Unlike a theme hack, this is a standalone application that can be easily installed and uninstalled, without having to resort to ugly things like patching and other hacks. It also uses the DWM (unlike the classic themes), so you're not missing out on the graphically accelerated (and actually faster) UI with aero. You can also uninstall it cleanly if you're not happy with it

Comment: I've minified my images - since they're huge screenshots. Full sized links http://i.stack.imgur.com/OZiNp.jpg and http://i.stack.imgur.com/H1jx7.png