# Windows 10 Classic Theme

Tags: windows, windows-10, themes

Expanding on [How can I make Windows 8 use the classic theme?](https://superuser.com/questions/513492/how-can-i-make-windows-8-use-the-classic-theme) and [Windows 10 TenForums: Windows Classic Look Theme in Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/customization/11432-windows-classic-look-theme-windows-10-a.html) -- how does one use Windows 10 with the old classic theme?

[image]

There's a [Windows 10 theme over at DeviantArt](http://kizo2703.deviantart.com/art/Windows-classic-theme-for-Windows-8-RTM-8-1-10-325642288) but it does not work with the final RTM:

[image]

Also, your vote over at [Windows 10 UserVoice: Windows Classic Look Theme in Windows 10](https://windows.uservoice.com/forums/265757-windows-feature-suggestions/suggestions/9193677-windows-classic-look-theme-in-windows-10) would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried any of those solutions? They might do it.

Comment: [How to change Theme, Lock Screen & Wallpaper in Windows 10](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-theme-lock-screen-wallpaper-windows-10)

Comment: @JaredAllard yes, I tried Anixx' solution but it broke my system and I had to reinstall.

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm afraid it's not that easy when it comes to the old classic theme.

Comment: @MarkBoulder Option 1 from Anixx' solution worked for me when using the "enable classic theme now (for new processes only)" option, I didn't try the permanent install.

Comment: The new modern windos theme is awful,personal opinion: i prefer the old xp,2000,windows 7 way..

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at this thread:

http://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=113024&p=777781&hilit=classictheme#p777781

They're discussing/testing how to modify windows binary files to "get back" to classic interface by "unusual" methods, rather than just turning colors into gray!
But it appears to be very complex due to totally different structure of explorer, windows manager and whatelse in Windows 10 w.r.t. previous versions.
Note: be sure to create a restore point before running ClassicTheme.exe for testing! It can screw up whole interface!

For the start menu, things are easier thanks to ClassicShell: http://www.classicshell.net/gallery/

Additionally, try googling for:
Classic AE by Saarineames (download from deviantart)
Aero Lite Theme (among other things, make windows border larger than one pixel, for better resize and better visibility)

You can also play (carefully) with registry keys:

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\DWM  *(you can add **AccentColorInactive** key here, or edit existing keys)*
- KEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/get-colored-window-title-bar-windows-10

Ultimate Windows Tweaker is also an amazing tool:

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/image-gallery-for-uwt4

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 11 and Windows 10 version 1903 and above I suggest to use [Explorer Patcher](https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher) and [ClassicThemeTray](https://github.com/spitfirex86/ClassicThemeTray):

[image: Windows 11 in classic theme, with the help of ExplorerPatcher and OpenShell]

Check [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher/discussions/167) for a detailed tutorial.

Comment: Why is the downvote?

Comment: This really, really should have been the accepted answer. Very nice solution by integrating ExplorerPatcher and OpenShell!

Comment: @march_happy thanks. Updated this as EP now supports latest versions of Win10 as well.

Comment: This is looking very interesting, but unfortunately it looks like you have to build it yourself.

Comment: @convert build what?

Comment: Build the tools linked in the answer.

Comment: @convert no, you can download them.

Comment: But I can download only the sorce codethere, which I then have to build myself. Hope now is clear what I was tallking about.

Comment: @convert look better

Comment: Sory posibly I am just blind, but have seen only sorce code and no exe.

Comment: @convert it seems so. https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher/releases ; https://github.com/spitfirex86/ClassicThemeTray/releases

Answer (score 1):

Its impossible to change it to:

[image: Windows XP]

If you are REALLY desperate for the classic theme, [downgrade to Windows 7](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/roll-back-windows-7-from-windows-8-3459580/). Or go along with this

[image: Windows 8 Version of classic]